# Problems deploying a project with docker

Tags: spring, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I recently started trying to use the docker in a more advanced way. I had already used it to create mysql server and postgres server containers. At the moment I have a Spring test project, which runs normally when starting up. But I tried to instantiate the same with docker, it successfully creates a mysql server, and instantiates a tomcat, but it does not go up the project itself.

Dockerfile content:

```
FROM tomcat:9-jre11
ENV CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Duser.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo -Xms1024m -Xmx2560m -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow"
ADD ./smartCircuit/target/*.war $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/
EXPOSE 8080
CMD catalina.sh run;
```

docker-compose.yaml content:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    container_name: mysql-container
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'smart_circuit'
      MYSQL_USER: 'user'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    ports:
      # <Port exposed> : < MySQL Port running inside container>
      - '3307:3306'
    expose:
      # Opens port 3306 on the container
      - '3306'
      # Where our data will be persisted
    volumes:
      - my-db:/var/lib/mysql
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: tomcat
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      DB_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql-container:3306/smart_circuit?useSSL=false
      DB_USER: user
      DB_PASSWORD: password
    links:
      - db:mysql-container
# Names our volume
volumes:
  my-db:
```

I'm expecting my application to start and be accessible when I use the command "sudo docker-compose up --build". For example I have one RestController mapped "project" with a method mapped "find" which receives an id and either retrieves it when found or throws a NotFoundException.
When I run it through InteliJ without docker it works, but when I start it through docker I get a Tomcat 404 Not Found return.
Basically I can access the mysql instance with no problem and the tomcat is kind of working, but the project itself is not being deployed.

Comment: Can you edit the question to correctly format the Dockerfile and Docker Compose YAML file?  Can you say more specifically what behavior you're expecting and what you're actually seeing?

Comment: Done. Please warn me if it's enough or you need more details and wich?